# Mysterious Assertion Failed popup

Tags: windows-7, windows, c++

I'm not sure if I'm asking in the right forum, so if I'm not please tell me where I should post it.

I have Win7 Enterprise SP1 64bit.

Every day I have `Assetion failed!` popup window:

[image]

The mentioned file does not exist. Moreover, the drive `d` does not exist.
I ran antivirus and different anti-malware softwares, but they revealed nothing.
I tried to delete that `tmp` file, but it shows different file on every popup.

I used to have `d` drive as cd-rom drive, but now it's a different letter.

What can I do to figure out what it is?

**UPDATE**

I've uninstalled all Adobe products. msconfig->Startup still shows `Adobe ARM`.

[image]

But, **Autoruns** does not show `Adobe ARM` anymore

[image]

Now, when I re-install the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, that popup is shown again

[image]

Comment: Is this is happening every day after the boot? If so, examine your startup items. [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) is a good tool for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second path quoted is simply the path to a file for a library during compile-time (or other) **on the system it was compiled on**. It isn't indicative of a bug or malware.

I would use "autoruns" as @harrymc suggested. based on the fact that Adobe is mentioned in the path, it happens at startup, and there is a reference to an installer: disable Adobe Update and anything adobe related that is set to Autorun at startup.

The installers use temporary filenames frequently, and this is also not an indicator of a problem *on its own*.

( see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249152/file-path-in-c-assert-not-found-on-my-disk )

ADDED

The "adelrcp" in the path suggests this is related to the PDF preview handler, which is probably a windows "shell context handler" (or similar). There is a Lightroom [support page](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/lightroom-error-assertion-failed-update.html) which suggests some things to check. The reasoning is that there is a "virtual (magic) folder" which points to a user folder that does not exist.

It may not match exactly, but might point you in the right direction. The content is quoted below:

> Open Windows Explorer.
>
> Go to C:\Users[your user name].
>
> Check for the folder named Pictures.
>
> If you don't see the folder, create a folder named Pictures under
>   folder C:\Users[your user name].
>
> Restart Lightroom. If the error recurs, restart your computer, then
>   retry. If the error recurs, continue to the next step.
>
> Click the Windows Start button.
>
> Type "regedit" in the Search program and files field, and press the
>   Enter key.
>
> Back up your registry by choosing File > Export. Give the backup copy
>   of the registry a name and location you can remember.
>
> Navigate to the registry key:
>   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
>   \User Shell Folders]
>
> Look at the value for the My Pictures entry. The Windows default is:
>   %USERPROFILE%\Pictures, which is the Pictures folder under
>   C:\Users[your user name]. If another folder is listed, check Windows
>   Explorer for that folder. If it does not exist, you have two options.
>
> Create the folder with that name in the location indicated in the registry entry.
>
> If the Pictures folder exists under your user name folder, double-click the My Pictures entry, and reset the value to:
>   %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
>
> Quit the registry editor. Log off from your account and back on, or
>   restart your computer, then restart Lightroom

Comment: I've added an update to my post. Can you take a look please?

Comment: added something. luckily, you have identified the source of the issue.

Comment: I verified that all folder listed in registry exist and accessible, but I still get that error.